# predict.randomForest() returns empty rows beneath correct data with type="prob" selected

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest

Here is some dummy code relating to the `iris` dataset, which produces the problem that I'm having.

```
iris <- read.csv("~/Rdata/iris.csv")
library(randomForest)
fit <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)

iris$guess <- predict(fit, type="prob")
View(iris)
```

You will see the new `GUESS` column is 450 records long, while `iris` is only 150 records long. But the predictions seem to be correct, and this problem goes away if I remove `type="prob"` from the code.

Comment: On another note, `iris` is a built-in dataset - you don't need to assign it manually. Try typing `iris` in a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation for the `type` argument at `?predict.randomForest` indicates that for `type='prob'`, you'll receive a matrix of predicted probabilities for the different potential response classes.

You'll see this when you look at the `predict` outcome by itself:

```
head(predict(fit, type="prob"), 10)

#       setosa  versicolor virginica
# 1  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 2  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 3  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 4  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 5  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 6  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 7  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 8  1.0000000 0.000000000         0
# 9  0.9945355 0.005464481         0
# 10 1.0000000 0.000000000         0
```

Since there are 3 classes (species) and 150 observations, there are 450 predictions. When you this matrix of predictions to the data.frame, R removes the dimensions from it and adds it as a single long column.

If you keep the `type` as the default `'response'`, then R will return the class that has the highest predicted probability. For example, compare:

```
levels(iris$Species)[apply(predict(fit,type="prob"), 1, which.max)]
```

with

```
predict(fit)
```